# Using Pelican's image_process plugin, how do I tell it to use the original file as one of the srcset values? eg. srcset="the_original_image.jpg, 3x"

Tags: python, plugins, pelican

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
IMAGE_PROCESS = {
    'crisp': {'type': 'responsive-image',
              'srcset': [('1x', ["scale_in 800 600 True"]),
                         ('2x', ["USE THE ORIGINAL IMAGE"]),
                        ],
               'default': '1x',
             },
}
```

More explanation: The image_process plugin automates the creation of different versions of an image for devices with different resolutions, among other things. But there seems to be no way to tell it to use the original image as one of the versions to use. This is what I want to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question?, I don't see any!

Comment: Create a list in which you store all images possible and add the default image to it. Then you 'take' your images only out of the list.

Comment: @h_e_u_r_e_k_a, this is a pelican-specific question.

Comment: so why is there a tag **_python_**